# How to create a docx file with Angular, using for statements?

Tags: angular, docx

I am using Angular and the docx module to create a docx file containing data that was given by users. The goal is to create a docx file with the click of a simple button. It's about brewers and beers and should look something like this.

Brewer1

1. Beer 1, Description 1, Percentage 1
2. Beer 2, Description 2, Percentage 2

Brewer2

1. Beer 1, Description 1, Percentage 1
2. Beer 2, Description 2, Percentage 2

I have already done this with Java and the examples gives look very similar to what I've done in Java before. However the methods used in these examples don't seem to exist anymore. (The example: https://runkit.com/dolanmiu/docx-demo10)

So according to the example I would do something like

```
for(let brewer of brewers)
   doc.addParagraph(brewer.name)
   for(let beer of brewer.beers)
       doc.addParagraph(beer.name)
```

The problem is that I can only use doc.addSection() which seems complex for my goal and which doesn't allow me to loop twice. (Documentation: https://docx.js.org/#/usage/sections).

So basically my question comes down to
     1) Are there easier ways to create a docx file based of a database?
  or 2) Why can't my doc object use the method 'addParagraph()'?

Answer (score 0):

Map your data structure to an array of paragraphs and use it in addSection

```
doc.addSection({
  children: brewers.map(brewer => [
    new Paragraph({ children: [new TextRun(brewer.name)],}),
    ...brewer.beers.map(beer => new Paragraph({ children: [new TextRun(beer.name)],}))
  ])
});
```

Comment: Took me on my way of finding a similar solution by using 2 for statements creating an array of Paragraphs and adding it to children. Thank you!